# How can I group an array by distinct 'name' and put associated values into a sub-array for each name?

Tags: php, arrays

I've done much searching on this and can't seem to find an example that helps my case.

I have an array like so:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'name' => 'iPhone 5'
      'data' => 7
  1 => 
    array
      'name' => 'iPhone 5'
      'data' => 5
  2 => 
    array
      'name' => 'iPhone 5'
      'data' => 4
  3 => 
    array
      'name' => 'Lumia 1020'
      'data' => 3
  4 => 
    array
      'name' => 'Lumia 1020'
      'data' => 3
  5 => 
    array
      'name' => 'Lumia 1020'
      'data' => 8
etc.
```

What I am trying to achieve is a new array with grouping like the following:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'name' => 'iPhone 5'
      'data' => 
        array
          0 => 7
          1 => 5
          2 => 4
  1 => 
    array
      'name' => 'Lumia 1020'
      'data' => 
        array
          0 => 3
          1 => 3
          2 => 8
  2 => 
    array
      'name' => 'Samsung Galaxy S4'
      'data' => 
        array
          0 => 8
          1 => 5
          2 => 6
```

Any pointers would me hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work.

```
$output = array();

//loop over the input array
foreach($input as $phone){
    //get the name for our key
    $name = $phone['name'];
    $data = $phone['data'];
    //if the name doesn't exist in our output...
    if(!isset($output[$name])){
        //add it
        $output[$name] = array('name'=>$name, 'data'=>array($data));
    } else {
        //else, add data
        $output[$name]['data'][] = $data;
    }
}
//get the values from the array to re-index numerically
$newData = array_values($output);
//display
echo "<pre>".print_r($newData, true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you for a quick response :)